# what is the maximum font-weight value in multiples of hundred

Tags: css, fonts

In CSS when we specify font-weight in multiples of hundred as font-weight: 500; font-weight: 700; so on.

Is there any maximum value for font-weight such that font-weight will be extra bold or maximum at certain range, say : font-weight:1500 like that

Answer (score 13):

`900` is the largest value as defined in the [CSS2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-boldness):

> `normal | bold | bolder | lighter`
> `100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900`
> `inherit`
>
> The 'font-weight' property selects the weight of the font. The values '100' to '900' form an ordered sequence, where each number indicates a weight that is at least as dark as its predecessor. The keyword 'normal' is synonymous with '400', and 'bold' is synonymous with '700'. Keywords other than 'normal' and 'bold' have been shown to be often confused with font names and a numerical scale was therefore chosen for the 9-value list.

Comment: Side note: CSS Fonts Module Level 3, which is now Candidate Recommendation, does not change this. Side note 2: very few fonts commonly used on web pages have typefaces with weight larger than 700, so the *practical* upper limit is 700 for most fonts (and 400 for many fonts), as far as proper typography (as opposite to synthesized bolding) is considered.

Answer (score 8):

`font-weight` valid range is 100 - 900.

**Reference**

http://www.css3.com/css-font-weight/

Comment: Another thing to note is that only the multiples of 100 are allowed in CSS.  You can't have a weight of say, 350.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer 2018 is `1000`.

[CSS Fonts Module Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-css-fonts-4-20180920/#font-weight-numeric-values) allows `font-weight` to have any of the following values

- Any [number](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-css-values-3-20180814/#numbers) between `1` and `1000` (inclusive)
- `normal`, equivalent to 400
- `bold`, equivalent to 700
- The [relative weights](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-css-fonts-4-20180920/#relative-weights) `bolder` or `lighter`

[Earlier versions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-fonts-3-20180920/#font-weight-prop) only allowed the following values: `normal`, `bold`, `bolder`, `lighter`, `100`, `200`, `300`, `400`, `500`, `600`, `700`, `800` and `900`.

Answer (score 1):

`font-weight` value ranges from 100 to 900.

[Read here.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/)